# Common entity in multiple db contexts Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a game and divided my domain in three modules. My first idea was to create multiple database context as it should suit quite well my purpose the problem is that some of entities are common for all modules but in different modules they have different behaviours. Example of this is Player entity I want to have different Player domain objects but both should map to one database table so inheritance is not an option for me as I don't want to inherit behaviour from other modules.

In Economy context Player looks

```
public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Player> entity)
    {
        entity.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        entity.HasOne(x => x.PlayerBuildings)
            .WithOne(x => x.Player)
            .HasForeignKey<Player>(x => x.Id);
        entity.HasOne(x => x.Store)
            .WithOne(x => x.Player)
            .HasForeignKey<Player>(x => x.Id);
        entity.HasOne(x => x.ConstructionQueue)
            .WithOne(x => x.Player)
            .HasForeignKey<Player>(x => x.Id);

        entity.ToTable("Player");
    }
```

In World context it looks

```
public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Player> entity)
{
    entity.HasKey(c => c.Id);
    entity.ToTable("Player");
}

public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Realm> entity)
{
    entity.HasKey(c => c.Id);
    entity.HasMany(x => x.Players)
            .WithOne(x => x.Realm)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.RealmId);
        entity.ToTable("Realm");
}
```

When I run "add-migration name" it adds migration correctly but in both modules it generates create table sql. But it should be created only once and extend later. Do you have any hints ?

Comment: Add the second one(world) as a separate migration after applying the 1st one(player)?

Comment: Muqeet the problem is that in EF core 2.0 I see that we have file ContextNameModelSnapshot and migrations are generated based on it so applying first migration and later generating second doesn't help. As it looks that migration engine looks on this ModelSnapshot file and in my second context this file is empty so it recreates all entities which I have in my context. I can for example generate migration and manualy tweak it but I wonder if there is a better way to achieve it as I think its rather common approach that we divide contexts to reflect our domain bounderies.

Comment: Did you found any answer. I am facing the same. Please share if you got it already